# Stream PDF to Byte Array

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, arrays

I'm trying to load a pdf file to byte array, but after the code runs the byte array length is zero.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The project is vs 2010, running win 7 32 bit os in vm 9x.   Hopefully there is a simple fix to this problem.  Thanks in advance.

[Demonstrates the code I'm using to stream the pdf file to byte array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJgtP.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the path is not correct. There is a space in the file name.

Comment: Both the path and file string were correct.  The problems was simple enough the file was empty.  I discovered this after my original post and was a bit embarrassed to admit the over site.

Comment: The path was correct.  The file I was referencing turned out to be empty.  One last this to share, there is a property on the pdf viewer which needs the documents property to be set to get it to work.  The render-er works as demonstrated below, but the viewer is better it that it has additional features that make it more desirable to use.  Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strId = gridViewMain.SelectedRows[0].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strId))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery_GetAttachmentById, objConn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attachId", strId);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            SqlCommandBuilder sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            da.Fill(dt);

            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

            byte[] PDFBytes = (byte[])dr["attachment"];
            LoadPdf(PDFBytes);
        }

    }

    public void LoadPdf(byte[] pdfBytes)
    {
        var PDFstream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
        LoadPdf(PDFstream);
    }

    public void LoadPdf(Stream pdfstream)
    {
        // Create PDF Document
        var pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load(pdfstream);

        // Load PDF Document into WinForms Control
        pdfRenderer1.Load(pdfDocument);    
    }
}
```